# RuntimeException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: ERROR reCAPTCHA Enterprice Android

Tags: android, google-api, recaptcha

**I am getting the following runtime exception while initializing reCAPTCHA API in android. Can anyone help me with this issue?**

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: Failed to fetch data for local cache - status: 400
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.TaskUtil.setResultOrApiException(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.recaptcha.zzax.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-recaptcha@@16.0.1:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.recaptcha.zzad.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-recaptcha@@16.0.1:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.recaptcha.zzb.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-recaptcha@@16.0.1:3)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1184)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1143)
```

**initialization code:**

```
Recaptcha.getClient(this)
            .init(API_KEY_HERE)
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                this
            ) { handle ->
                recaptchaHandle = handle
            }
            .addOnFailureListener(
                this
            ) { e ->
                e.printStackTrace()
                if (e is ApiException) {
                    val apiException = e as ApiException
                    val apiErrorStatus: Int = apiException.statusCode
                    // Handle api errors ...
                } else {
                    // Handle other failures ...
                }
            }
```

**manifest code:**

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_api_key" />
```

Comment: Any update on this. Did you find out why this was happening?

Comment: Hi. Due to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions) the reCAPTCHA Android library is part of the Google Play services SafetyNet APIs. And I suppose that 
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-recaptcha:VERSION` you may use only if you enabled ENTERPRISE in [Google Recaptchure](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/). However, this is just my assumption.